# How to call web service from javascript file in alfresco 4.2.C

Tags: web-services, alfresco

I created execute script rule in alfresco and i kept my javascript file in Company Home>Data Dictionary>script folder.

My Rule is as follows:

All Items > Executes script 'dataFilesScript.js' > Items are created or entered this folder >Finish

1). My Js script is as follows.

```
var simplehttpresult = "";

try {

   simplehttpresult = SimpleHttpConnection.getContentAsString("http://myip:myport/alfresco/service/demo/simple");
 }catch(ex){
    error = String(ex)
}
```

2).I add following lines in web-scripts-application-context.xml

```
<bean id="webscript.org.alfresco.demo.simple.get" 
      class="org.alfresco.module.demoscripts.SimpleWebScript"
      parent="webscript">
      <property name="repository" ref="repositoryHelper" />
      <property name="serviceRegistry" ref="ServiceRegistry" />

  </bean>
```

3).My simple.get.desc.xml file

```
<webscript>
  <shortname>The World's Simplest Webscript</shortname>
  <description>Hands back a little bit of JSON</description>
  <url>/demo/simple</url>
  <authentication>none</authentication>
  <format default="">argument</format>
  <family>Alfresco Java-Backed WebScripts Demo</family>
</webscript>
```

4). I add following lines script-services-context.xml

```
 <bean id="httpUtilsScript" parent="baseJavaScriptExtension" 
        class="org.um.alfresco.SimpleHttpConnection">
        <property name="extensionName">
            <value>SimpleHttpConnection</value>
        </property>     
    </bean>
```

5).My Java file is as follows.

```
public class SimpleWebScript extends AbstractWebScript
{
    public void execute(WebScriptRequest req, WebScriptResponse res)
        throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            // build a json object
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

            // put some data on it
            obj.put("field1", "data1");

            // build a JSON string and send it back
            String jsonString = obj.toString();
            res.getWriter().write(jsonString);
        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {
            throw new WebScriptException("Unable to serialize JSON");
        }
    }    
}
```

.when my rule is executed. It's working fine in Alfresco 4.0 but it is not working for 4.2.c.
In Alfresco 4.2.C My action code was called only once...Any other configuration settings are Required in 4.2.C
Please suggest.....

Comment: I assume your script works when you call it otherwise (ie. not from Alfresco)?
And also, you can call some other web services (ie get a page off of random Internet site)?

Comment: Can you share the implementation of your `org.um.alfresco.SimpleHttpConnection` class?